# How to select random three rows in Sybase against value check for other column

Tags: sql, sybase

I have a table like below with approx 1 million rows.
**col2** has all the alphabets(consonant + vowels)
**col1** has random words

```
COL1          COL2 ......
val1          A
val2          A
val3          A
val4          A
val5          B
val6          B
val7          B
val8          B
.             .
.             .
.             .
.             .
.val100000    Z
```

Now i want to get the result as random three rows with `col2 in (A,E,I,O,U)`

As a hack I used *min* and *max* function to get the two numbers.But that doesn't behold the random property.

Any help would be greatly appreciated here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `NEWID()`,

like this

```
select * 
from (select row_number() over (partition by col2 order by NEWID()) rownum, m.*      from myTable m
where m.col2 in (A,E,I,O,U)) sel
where sel.rownum=1
```

Comment: THis is giving me just one row against A.

Comment: Better use ORDER BY RAND2()